# Historical data in array - yql

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I have this script to get the historical data from last year to today. The script is running good with one stock (in this example "mo"). I build an array because I want 6 stocks and the loop needs to build 6 tables. If I replace the stock name "mo" with my array name I get error.

```
var yyyy = new Date().getFullYear();
    var mm = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = "0" + mm;
    }

    var dd = new Date().getDate();
    var endDate = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    var startDate = (yyyy - 1) + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = 'mo' and startDate = '" + startDate + "' and endDate = '" + endDate + "'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var myTable = "";
            myTable += "<br /><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='500' bgcolor='green'>";
            myTable += "<tr>";
            myTable += "<td>Date</td><td>Open</td><td>Low</td><td>High</td><td>Volume</td><td>Close Price</td>";
            myTable += "</tr>";

            $.each(data.query.results.quote, function (index, item) {

                myTable += "<tr><td>" + item.Date + "</td><td>" + item.Open + "</td><td>" + item.Low + "</td><td>" + item.High + "</td><td>" + item.Volume + "</td><td>" + item.Close + "</td></tr>";

            });

            myTable += "</table>";
            $("#quotes").html(myTable);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#quotes").html('<p>Something has gone terribly wrong.</p>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: where's the array code? Why can't you make request for each one? Did you try debugging in the YQL console?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build 6 table queries. You can use the "IN" keyword. Sample query if you want historical data for "YHOO", "GOOG" and "AAPL" stock

`select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol IN ("YHOO","GOOG","AAPL") and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"`

Test it out in YQL console [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20IN%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22AAPL%22)%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222009-09-11%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222010-03-10%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)